# Grails Searchable Plugin Many-to-Many search

Tags: grails, many-to-many, grails-orm, grails-searchable, searchable-plugin

I have domain class User which has many-to-many relationship to domain class LibraryElement. I am trying to filter all the library elements, with certain text in it, that belong to User. This is how the searchable properties and relationship is defined:

User side:

```
static searchable = {
    id name: 'userId'
    libraryElements component: true
}

static hasMany = [libraryElements: LibraryElement]
```

LibraryElement side:

```
static searchable = {
    users component: true
}

static belongsTo = User
static hasMany = [users: User]
```

I am trying to execute search like this:

```
LibraryElement.search("userId:" + userId + " libraryElementName:" + searchWord + "*")
```

I am getting 0 results even though in database there is a data that should be hit by this search.

Comment: What is libraryElementName, i didnt see it in LibraryElement, can please elaborate.

Comment: It is a string field inside LibraryElement domain.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this:

```
LibraryElement.search(searchWord +" AND userId:userId", params)
```

?